# How can I disable crickets in the modpack 'Live in the Woods'?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

The crickets in the modpack *Live in the Woods* are driving me crazy. They span on my plants and destroy my salat and carrots. How can I disable them or avoid that they span next to my potatoes?

Comment: Just received an answer from Amber Campbell, the woman who created the mod pack. This suggest "**Use Garden Soil instead and they won't be able to trample it. :)**"

Answer (score 1):

Found an solution to my own question:

You need:
Mindcraft Forge for Minecraft 1.7.10 (included in the modpack already)

Davidee's GUI Library - Create better GUIs!
1.7.10 GUILib (fixed forceclose when pressing f6)
https://github.com/joserobjr/GuiLib/releases (Scroll down to "1.7.10.0: Ported to Minecraft 1.7.10" > Open the "Assets" > Download the "GuiLib-1.7.10.0.jar" only)

Mob Spawn Controls 2!
http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1290704-mob-spawn-controls-2-back-better-than-ever-updated

After adding all those files to your "mods" directory, start the game.
Load your savegame and press escape. Go to the options menu to change/remove the key-bindings of "F6" (Streaming).

Back in your game, press F6 to launch the "Mod Span Controls". Here you go to

1. Configs
2. List item
3. By Entity
4. Ambient
5. Choose "Cricket" and click "edit"
6. Find the green colored lines, for example "Vanilla.Jungle" and un-tick the Checkbox "Enable". Disable all Areas (or just those where you have setup your House/Garden) and save the changes.

I hope i could help here :)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to marcus' answer (which would be good enough for me), there are other mods that change whether entities spawn, where and in what numbers.

Try JAS (just another spawner, i prefer that one) or custom mob spawner (dr zhark's mo creatures mod uses that one). Their config files are very easy to edit.

I haven't played life in the woods, but i'm willing to bet that you already have one of the three mentioned mods in there already and you don't have to install anything at all.

Last - somewhat harsh - alternative is to simply delete "animals+" mod. They fixed the stupid crickets from 1.8+ but they are still broken in 1.7.10.